# Can see only 4 locations in my Azure Trial Subscription

Tags: azure, location, subscription

Really puzzled why I am not seeing all locations - only 4 - US West, US East, Japan West and Japan East in my trial subscription. Is there any filtering I inadvertently setup?

Any pointers would be really helpful

Shas

Answer (score 0):

I am giving many workshops for Azure and I see this behavior a lot for [Azure Passes](http://www.microsoftazurepass.com/) (also kind of trial accounts) but have not seen this for [Azure Trials](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/).

I noticed that I have more location options in the new Azure portal (https://portal.azure.com) and less in the old management portal (https://manage.windowsazure.com).

Also to consider, not all services are available at all locations. But the standard services like VMs or storage should be available everywhere. You can check via the [service overview](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/regions/#services) whether your desired service is available.

Comment: Thanks for confirming the occurrence as per your experience. As per my latest observation it seems it is not allowing me from new portal to create anything in classic mode in any other locations other than the 4 i.e. Central US, Southeast Asia, Japan East, Japan West. I can see the other locations in the location drop down however when I select any one it raises the error that "your subscription doesn't allow storage account in this location". If I try from old portal I cannot see anything other than the 4 locations to select from. So it seems these 4 are somehow related to the classic mode.